# Download CSV file using Google Drive V3(V2 works perfect) throws error 403

Tags: php, google-app-engine, csv, google-drive-api

I m using **DRIVE V2** WITH **Service Account to download CSV file**,This one is working fine. I want to migrate DRIVE V2 to DRIVE V3 .So i changed my script as per below google documents

**[I. Download a file in drive V3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#downloading_a_file)**

**[PHP Library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/releases/tag/1.1.7) & [Drive API V3](https://gist.github.com/bshaffer/9bb2cdccd315880ab52f) used in this sample:**

**1.Sample script download CSV file using Drive V3**

**Method used: Using alt=media**

**Reason: this method only available in DRIVE V3**

```
<?php
set_include_path( get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'Google' );
require_once 'Google/autoload.php';
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/Drive.php';
try{
    //Get service document
    $service = get_service_document();
    //Download a csv file
    $data = $service->files->get("FILE ID", array( 'alt' => 'media'));
   print_r($data);
}
catch(Exception $e){
    print_r($e->getMessage());
}
//function to get service
function get_service_document(){
    $userstamp='user@example.com';

//Enable below two lines if let know the clientid,tokens,etc.,
    $driveService=buildServiceDrive($userstamp,"SERVICE_ACCOUNT","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive","KEY.p12");
    return $driveService;
}
//building service
function buildServiceDrive($userEmail,$service_id,$scope,$service_filename) {
    $key = file_get_contents($service_filename);
    $auth = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        $service_id,
        array($scope),
        $key);
    $auth->sub = $userEmail;
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAssertionCredentials($auth);
    return new Google_Service_Drive($client);
}
```

**RESULT:**
I got the below issue

```
Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/0B5pkfK_IBDxjeHlTTDFFY01CXzQ?alt=media: (302)
Moved Temporarily
The document has moved here.
```

After clicked here. I saw below error.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

**II. [Download a file in Drive V2](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/manage-downloads#alternate_method_using_downloadurl)**

I used alternate method to download CSV file from drive.

**[PHP Library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/releases/tag/1.1.7) & [Drive API V2](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Service/Drive.php) used in this sample:**

**2.Sample Script download CSV file using Drive V2**

**Method used :  Alternate method: using downloadUrl**

```
<?php
set_include_path( get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'Google' );
require_once 'Google/autoload.php';
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/Drive.php';
try{

    //Get service document
    $service = get_service_document();
    $data = $service->files->get("FILE ID");
    $url=$data->downloadUrl;
    $data=downloadFile($service,$url);
    print_r($data);
}
catch(Exception $e){
    print_r($e->getMessage());
}

//Alternate method using download URL
function downloadFile($service, $downloadUrl)
{
    if ($downloadUrl) {
        $request = new Google_Http_Request($downloadUrl, 'GET', null, null);
        $httpRequest = $service->getClient()->getAuth()->authenticatedRequest($request);
        if ($httpRequest->getResponseHttpCode() == 200) {
            return $httpRequest->getResponseBody();
        } else {
            echo "errr";
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        echo "empty";
        return null;
    }
}
//function to get service
function get_service_document(){
$driveService =buildServiceDrive(user@example.com',"SERVICE-ACCOUNT","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive","KEY.p12");
    return $driveService;
}
//building service
function buildServiceDrive($userEmail,$service_id,$scope,$service_filename) {
    $key = file_get_contents($service_filename);
    $auth = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        $service_id,
        array($scope),
        $key);
    $auth->sub = $userEmail;
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAssertionCredentials($auth);
    return new Google_Service_Drive($client);
}
```

**Result:**

i got CSV file records, working fine
[image]

Plz help me resolve to download a CSV file using G DRIVE V3. Is there any regression or functions lagging b/w V2, V3?

Comment: Updated the posting.

Comment: It's difficult to understand your setup; I get you've been trying to rule out issues by trying different ways of communicating with Drive, but one would have to go and read the 7 different tutorials you linked. You should try to shrink it down, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Perhaps it is sufficient to post the lines that fail and the error.

Comment: thanks Pietro  Saccardi, Now i changed hope can understand!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Google Drive API for PHP is beta version, realize that some errors can be experienced by developers.

> Error calling GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/0B5pkfK_IBDxjeHlTTDFFY01CXzQ?alt=media:
>   (302) Moved Temporarily The document has moved **here**.

In this case, **here**'s link is:
https://www.googleapis.com/**download**/drive/v3/files/0B5pkfK_IBDxjeHlTTDFFY01CXzQ?alt=media

You can see the API Server suggest the new link "download" before "/drive...".

In Google Drive Client Library V3, here is the solution you can fix manually by adding the following code to src/Google/Http/REST.php after line 147:

```
if($requestUrl=='drive/v3/files/{fileId}' && $params['alt']['value']=='media')
  $requestUrl = "download/".$requestUrl;
```

Hope this help... :)