# ERR 403 - (User Rate Limit Exceeded) when listing files in V3

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I  want to get the files name from one folder Using  `Files.List` using the Google Drive v3 API and the Google PHP Client library.

I don't want to check the moved files to trash from that folder, so I used Drive API function `getExplicitlyTrashed()` to find what are the files in trash to filter those files

Latest release of Google PHP client library: [1.1.7](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/releases/tag/1.1.7)

Google Drive V3 file: https://gist.github.com/bshaffer/9bb2cdccd315880ab52f

Also used src/Google/Http/REST.php in Drive v3 only updated as per below post reply:  [Download CSV file using Google Drive V3(V2 works perfect) throws error 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35864527/download-csv-file-using-google-drive-v3v2-works-perfect-throws-error-403/36290123#36290123)

Sample Script Using Drive V3 method Files: List - List files from Folder not in trash

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
set_include_path( get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'Google' );
require_once 'Google/autoload.php';
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/Drive.php';
$service=get_service_document();
$folderid="FOLDER_ID";
$list_files=GetAllFilesName($service,$folderid);
for($i=0;$i<count($list_files);$i++){
    $id= $list_files[$i][0];
    $name=$list_files[$i][1];
    echo 'ID:'.$id.'<br>NAME:'.$name.'<br>';
}

function GetAllFilesName($service,$folderid){
// v3 To check explicitly trashed function we shld use optional parameter    
try{
            $optParams = array(
            'fields' =>'explicitlyTrashed'
        );
//Get list of files from folder
        $children1 = $service->files->listFiles(array(
            'q' => "'$folderid' in parents "));
        $filenamelist=array();
        foreach ($children1 as $child) {
                if ($service->files->get($child->getId(), $optParams)->getExplicitlyTrashed() == 1) continue;
                $fileid = $service->files->get($child->getId())->id;
                $filename = $service->files->get($child->getId())->name;
                $filenamelist[] = [$fileid,$filename];
              }
        return $filenamelist;
    }
    catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();//$filenamelisterr;
    }
}
//function to get service
function get_service_document(){
    $userstamp='user@example.com';
     $driveService =buildServiceDrive($userstamp,"SERVICE-ACCOUNT","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive","key.p12");
    return $driveService;
}
//building service
function buildServiceDrive($userEmail,$service_id,$scope,$service_filename) {
    $key = file_get_contents($service_filename);
    $auth = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        $service_id,
        array($scope),
        $key);
    $auth->sub = $userEmail;
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAssertionCredentials($auth);
    return new Google_Service_Drive($client);
}
```

My script could not list all files in that folder constantly. Each time calling some time working some time i m getting this below issue

Response:
[image]

2.Sample Script Using Drive V2 method Files: List - List files from Folder not in trash

Using Drive v2, my script working fine, I didn't get any 403 issue.

```
<?php
set_include_path( get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'GoogleV2' );
require_once 'GoogleV2/autoload.php';
require_once 'GoogleV2/Client.php';
require_once 'GoogleV2/Service/Drive.php';


$service=get_service_document();
$folderid="FOLDER-ID";
$list_files=GetAllFilesName($service,$folderid);
for($i=0;$i<count($list_files);$i++){
    $id= $list_files[$i][0];
    $name=$list_files[$i][1];
    echo 'ID:'.$id.'<br>NAME:'.$name.'<br>';
}
//print_r($list_files);

function GetAllFilesName($service,$folderid){
    try{
        $children1 = $service->children->listChildren($folderid);
        $filenamelist=array();
        foreach ($children1->getItems() as $child) {
            if($service->files->get($child->getId())->getExplicitlyTrashed()==1)continue;
            $fileid=$service->files->get($child->getId())->id;
            $filename=$service->files->get($child->getId())->title;
            $filenamelist[]=[$fileid,$filename];
        }
        return $filenamelist;
    }
    catch(Exception $ex){
        Echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
//function to get service
function get_service_document(){
  $userstamp='user@example.com';
  $driveService =buildServiceDrive($userstamp,"SERVICE-ACCOUNT","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive","KEY.p12");
    return $driveService;
}
//building service
function buildServiceDrive($userEmail,$service_id,$scope,$service_filename) {
    $key = file_get_contents($service_filename);
    $auth = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        $service_id,
        array($scope),
        $key);
    $auth->sub = $userEmail;
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAssertionCredentials($auth);
    return new Google_Service_Drive($client);
}
```

Response:

[image]

**Using Exponential Back up, we modified the script, But still 403 error is thrown..**

```
<?php
set_include_path( get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'Google' );
require_once 'Google/autoload.php';
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/Drive.php';

$service=get_service_document();
$folderid="FOLDER_ID"; 
$list_files=GetAllFilesName($service,$folderid);
for($i=0;$i<count($list_files);$i++){
    $id= $list_files[$i][0];
    $name=$list_files[$i][1];
    echo 'ID:'.$id.'<br>NAME:'.$name.'<br>';
}


function GetAllFilesName($service,$folderid){
    try{
        $n=5;
        $optParams = array(
            'fields' =>'explicitlyTrashed'
        );
        $children1 = $service->files->listFiles(array(
            'q' => "'$folderid' in parents "));
        $filenamelist=array();

        foreach ($children1 as $child) {
            try {
                if ($service->files->get($child->getId(), $optParams)->getExplicitlyTrashed() == 1) continue;
                $fileid = $service->files->get($child->getId())->id;
                $filename = $service->files->get($child->getId())->name;
                $filenamelist[] = [$fileid,$filename];
            }
            catch (apiServiceException $ex) {
                if ($ex->getCode() == 403
                    && ($ex->getErrors()[0]["reason"] == "rateLimitExceeded"
                        || $ex->getErrors()[0]["reason"] == "userRateLimitExceeded"
                        || $ex->getErrors()[0]["reason"] =="dailyLimitExceeded")
                ) {
                    // Apply exponential backoff.
                    usleep((1 << $n) * 1000000 + rand(0, 1000000));
                }
            }
        }
        return $filenamelist;
    }
    catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();//$filenamelisterr;
    }
}
//function to get service
function get_service_document(){
     $userstamp='user@example.com';
     $driveService =buildServiceDrive($userstamp,"SERVICE-ACCOUNT","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive","key.p12");
    return $driveService;
}
//building service
function buildServiceDrive($userEmail,$service_id,$scope,$service_filename) {
    $key = file_get_contents($service_filename);
    $auth = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        $service_id,
        array($scope),$key);
    $auth->sub = $userEmail;
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAssertionCredentials($auth);
    return new Google_Service_Drive($client);
}
```

Plz help me is there any other way on  how to use exponential back off, May be I didn't get it correctly on the application of the Expo. Back Off? We are running around it for the past 3 weeks, plz help. We need to deploy Drive V3. Any of ur suggestion/tips/ help would be really a great help for us.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Documentation tells you how to deal with this error message.

> 403: [User Rate Limit Exceeded](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#403_user_rate_limit_exceeded)
>
> The per-user limit from the Developer Console has been reached.
>
> {  "error": {   "errors": [    {
>       "domain": "usageLimits",
>       "reason": "userRateLimitExceeded",
>       "message": "User Rate Limit Exceeded"    }   ],   "code": 403,   "message": "User Rate Limit Exceeded"  } }
>
> Suggested actions:
>
> - Raise the per-user quota in the Developer Console project.
> - If one user
>     is making a lot of requests on behalf of many users of a Google Apps
>     domain, consider a Service Account with authority delegation (setting
>     the quotaUser parameter).
> - Use exponential backoff.

Basically you are encountering flood protection,  your code is running to fast you need to slow it down.  Why v2 doesn't show this and v3 does that is quite simply the fact that v3 is faster then v2 it is after all a newer API.

Solution:

[Implementing exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#exponential-backoff)

Exponential backoff is a standard error handling strategy for network applications in which the client periodically retries a failed request over an increasing amount of time. If a high volume of requests or heavy network traffic causes the server to return errors, exponential backoff may be a good strategy for handling those errors. Conversely, it is not a relevant strategy for dealing with errors unrelated to rate-limiting, network volume or response times, such as invalid authorization credentials or file not found errors.

Used properly, exponential backoff increases the efficiency of bandwidth usage, reduces the number of requests required to get a successful response, and maximizes the throughput of requests in concurrent environments.

Comment: Thanks Dalm To, I updated my post using exponential backoff.But still i m getting 403 issue.Plz help me to solve this

Comment: Hi Dalm To, Using exponential backoff also i m getting 403 User rate limit.Guide me how to use exponential back off.

Comment: your still going to fast then.   make sure you are adding enough time between each loop.  I normally add half a second for each loop.

Comment: Thanks Dalm To, Now i m getting occasionally 403 User rate limit.